# What's the purpose of "bar" in "var foo = function bar (){ ... }"?

Tags: javascript

In Douglas Crockford's book he writes a recursive function as:

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func){
   func(node);
   node = node.firstChild;
   while(node){
      walk(node,func);
      node = node.nextSibling;
   }
}
```

I've never seen a function defined as `var foo = function bar(){...}` - I've always seen the right side of the declaration be anonymou as: `var foo = function (){...}`

Is the only purpose of the name `walk` in the right side of the declaration to shorten the calling of `walk_the_DOM`? They seem to become separate names for an identical function. Perhaps I've misunderstood how this snippet works.

**Is there a functional reason for naming the function both in the variable declaration and the function construct?**

Comment: By the way, I'm not adept enough with the terminology yet perhaps "function construct" isn't the right thing to call it, I wouldn't mind being corrected / informed about that terminology too.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a functional reason for naming the function both in the variable declaration and the function construct?

Yes. `function bar() {}` causes the function's `name` property to be set to `bar`, which can be useful for, e.g., debugging in stack traces.

Regarding some of the naming confusion you alluded to, this might help:

```
function bar() {}
```

^ This is a *function declaration*, as it does not exist as part of an assignment expression.

```
var foo = function() {};
```

^ This is an *assignment expression* where the right-hand operand is a *function expression*, and where the function expression defines an *anonymous function*.

```
var foo = function bar() {};
```

^ This is an *assignment expression* where the right-hand operand is a *function expression*, and where the function expression defines a *named function*.

It's probably worth noting that *function declarations* can be referenced locally by their function name, so the following statements are *roughly* equivalent:

```
function bar() {}

var bar = function() {};
```

I say *roughly* equivalent, because the second statement still results in an *anonymous* function, rather than a *named* function. There's also a subtle difference in how function declarations get hoisted.  Consider the following, for example:

```
function test() {
    hello();

    var hello = function () { console.log('hello'); };
}

test();
// > TypeError: hello is not a function
```

Note that `hello` was technically defined where we tried to invoke it (the exception is simply that it's not a function (yet)).  This is due to variable hoisting.  As expected, though, we haven't yet *assigned* our function to the `hello` variable.  This is easier to show than to explain, really.  Basically, due to hoisting, the above `test` example is equivalent to:

```
function test() {
    var hello; // declared, but not assigned yet

    hello();

    hello = function () { console.log('hello'); }; // now the assignment happens
}
```

Compare that to an actual function declaration:

```
function test() {
    hello();

   function hello() { console.log('hello'); };
}

test();
// > "hello"
```

Notice that even though the declaration is *below* the invocation command, it still works, because function declarations get hoisted as a whole to the top of their scope (in this case, `test`).

If that's confusing, here's a more condensed description of behavior that might help: *declarations get hoisted*, not *assignments*. As long as you understand the difference between function declarations and function expressions, that's all you need to know. :)

Answer (score 2):

By writing `var foo = function (){...}` you are declaring a variable named `foo` that holds an anonymous function. By writing `var foo = function bar(){...}` you are declaring a variable named `foo` that holds a named function as `bar`. As @jmar777 pointed out in his answer, this is useful to follow stack traces when debugging and bug fixing.