# Getting object fields and calling object functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I just started fiddling around with JavaScript. Coming from Java and OO PHP things are getting weirder with every step :)

This is my introduction project to javascript in which I've set out to program multiplayer working version of Settlers of Catan. Code below is an attempt to store cube coordinates of N sized hexagonal map tiles in an array.

I've read you declare object in javascript by assigning functions to variables.

```
var Tile = function (x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
};

var Map = function () {
    var grid = [];

    function generate_map(radius) {
        for (width = -radius; width <= radius; width++) {
            var r1 = Math.max(-radius, -width - radius);
            var r2 = Math.min(radius, -width + radius);

            for (r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
                grid.push(new Tile(width, r, -width - r));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I've tried instantiating new Map object, calling its only function and outprinting the resulting values stores in grid[] array. But for each loop is not playing nice :( I get the unexpected identifier.

```
var main = function () {
    var basic_map = new Map();
    basic_map.generate_map(3);
    for each (var tile in basic_map.grid) {
        console.log(tile.x, tile.y, tile.z);
    }
};

main();
```

I am fully aware this is one of those face palm errors, but help would nevertheless be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: *unexpected identifier* - which one?

Comment: you should declare `width`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: syntax

Comment: @DanielA.White: width = -radius;

Comment: And why so many down-votes? I seriously can't understand all the frustration on this site :(

Comment: I recommend to read an introduction to OOP JS, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript or http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html

Comment: *"Coming from Java and OO PHP things are getting weirder with every step"* JavaScript is actually less magical here. `grid` and `generate_map` are simply two variables *local* to the `Map` function. They only exist while the function is executed. The do not *magically* become properties of the newly created object. You have to explicitly create the properties of the function (`this.foo = bar;`).

Comment: "grid and generate_map are simply two variables local to the Map function" - from my point of view, using functions for declaring classes and/or instantiating object from class is somewhat magical to say the least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
function generate_map(radius) {
```

...to this:

```
this.generate_map = function(radius) {
```

---

Edit: there are actually more issues than I at first realized.... :)

A few other tips:

*First*, I would recommend changing:

```
var Tile = function (x, y, z) {
```

...to simply be:

```
function Tile(x, y, z) {
```

(the same goes for Map). Your current solution works fine, but it's not very idiomatic, and until ES6 there was nothing in the spec that would cause `var Tile = function` to cause the resulting function's 'name' property to be set to "Tile", which is useful when it comes to debugging. I recently wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572252/whats-the-purpose-of-bar-in-var-foo-function-bar/31572271#31572271) that delves a bit more into the differences between, e.g., `function Foo() {}` and `var Foo = function() {}`.

*Second*, you probably want to rename `Map` to something else. `Map` is a core part of ES6 now (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

*Third*, even though you can create your `generate_map` function using `this.generate_map`, you may want to move it to the `Map's` prototype. Also, since you need to expose the `grid` value, you want to store it as a property, rather than a local variable scoped to the `NewMapName` constructor. E.g.,:

```
function NewMapName() {
    this.grid = [];
}

NewMapName.prototype.generateMap = function(radius) {
    // you can access the grid here via `this.grid`
    ...
};
```

By moving it to the prototype, that means all instances of `NewMapName` will share the same function reference, rather than it being created over-and-over-and-over (although maybe you really only create it once? Either way, it's more idiomatic, at a minimum). Note that I took some liberties with the "camelCasing" here (see the last point).

*Fourth*, your `generateMap` implementation is leaking some global variables (`width` and `r`, since you don't declare them with `var`). I would change that to this:

```
NewMapName.prototype.generateMap = function(radius) {
    for (var width = -radius; width <= radius; width++) {
        var r1 = Math.max(-radius, -width - radius);
        var r2 = Math.min(radius, -width + radius);

        for (var r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
            grid.push(new Tile(width, r, -width - r));
        }
    }
};
```

*Fifth*, your loop is kind of broken. I would refactor that as follows:

```
var main = function () {
    var basicMap = new NewMapName();
    basicMap.generateMap(3);

    basicMap.grid.forEach(function(tile) {
        console.log(tile.x, tile.y, tile.z);
    });
};

main();
```

*Lastly*, and probably most minor, is that in JavaScript-land, `camelCase` is far more dominant that `snake_case`, so `generate_map` might be "better" as `generateMap`.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be necessary to use ``this.grid`` instead of ``var grid``?

Comment: Maybe explain what the difference between `function foo(){}` and `this.foo = function() {}` is? `grid` has to be added to `this` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth explanation. There's one semicolon missing at the end of the generateMap, but that's beside the point :)

Comment: Great answer @jmar777! I really liked your explanation of the advantages of adding functions to the prototype. One note: if you need support for IE8 and below, use a normal for loop instead of ``arr.forEach()``.

Comment: @kamenjan good catch. *Technically* that would have still worked (google "Automatic Semicolon Insertion" when you really want to get confused), but yes, for consistency I try to always use semicolons, even where optional.